# Make a file in perforce depot download only?

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

Is it possible to make a file download only using perforce? In other words, as an example, we have a project.ini file that has various settings each user will download to work on a project. When they modify the project with their custom settings, it will modify the project.ini file with those custom settings. We do NOT want that project.ini file to get pushed back to the depot, it should only be downloaded as a base template for the user to modify further for their program UI. Hope that request makes sense.

Tried looking in the perforce client for ways to mark this file as a download only, but didn't see anything off hand.

Comment: What types of settings are these, exactly, and why would it not make sense to version them in the depot?  I'm wondering if it might make sense to branch them, rather than simply forbidding users to submit them at all.

Comment: I thought about branching them too, but was trying to keep it as simple as possible on the stream branching/side. The reason I don't want to version them is that it's basically a user preference file for a software UI. (Unreal Engine to be exact). I want them to download the pref file as a starting point, they can download and modify it, but i don't want 20 diff users constantly overwriting the original preference file template when they do a submission.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you're describing, the option that comes to my mind is using the `p4 protect` table to remove write access to that file for everyone.

You can do that through p4admin or via the CLI if you are a superuser.  (The `=` sign specifically denies a permission)

```
=write user * * -//depot_name/my_stream/configuration.ini
```

(In P4Admin you would choose `no write` from the dropdown of permissions instead of =write)

By putting this line at the bottom of my protections table, I remove write permission for everyone `*` (even myself and other super users). So if you ever want to make a change to it, you will need to change/remove that line and then add it back afterwards.

Users can still *try* to check out the file and submit it, but they will get a permission error when they try to submit.

If you combine that with setting the file's type to `+w` so it is always writable, then users can sync their workspace, and edit the file to their heart's content, without ever needing to check it out.

For more: [p4 protect documentation](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_protect.html)

Comment: I will give this a whirl, I think I already tried it, but I'll double check to make sure. I think the issue I had with this was all the errors that popped up and it aborted the submission because of the errors. (As in the other files that were perfectly fine to upload did not upload because of the errors). Was hoping to have something that ran more silently in the BG and quietly discarded the changes while letting the acceptable files through. (Which is how the p4ignore file operates with new files I think?)

Comment: Yeah, if that file is in a changelist then the whole thing can't be submitted (since submissions are atomic operations).  So it users would need to learn to move that file out of their changelists, or avoid checking it out. (Or doing a revert but leaving the file contents unchanged).

Comment: I might suggest removing `open` permission rather than just `write`, so that they can't open the file in the first place -- and make the file `+w` so that they'll be able to modify it locally without opening it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the great suggestions. We'll give it a whirl!